# problem in where clause of mysql query

Tags: mysql, syntax

Hi
I am generating messahedigest with SHA1 of a file(having extension .eml, as it contains email info)and then storing it to the table named web_de in column messagedigest. Why can't I execute following query in mysql ?? and also not in java...

```
SELECT slno FROM `webcrawler`.`web_de` 
where messagedigest='?Ê'?`®o1F±[øT¤?¿!€' ;
```

while I could execute query like

```
SELECT slno FROM `webcrawler`.`web_de` 
where messagedigest= ')@Ä€ó…ªã³§°óÚdv~Î¸`';
```

Pl note that I am trying to execute that query in mysql workbench 5.2.32 and using mysql 5.1

Can anybody help me out here please ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape that single quote in the first query:

```
where messagedigest = '?Ê''?`®o1F±[øT¤?¿!€' ;
```

Escaping is done by duplicating quotes:

```
''
```

(btw: as you see, even the stackoverflow syntax highlighter wasn't able to properly format your string...)

On the other hand, you shouldn't inline values in SQL for various reasons (security, performance). Since you're using Java, use a `PreparedStatement` instead:

```
// Prepare a statement with a bind variable : ?
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT slno FROM webcrawler.web_de WHERE messagedigest = ?");

// Bind your string to the first bind variable
ps.setString(1, "?Ê'?`®o1F±[øT¤?¿!€");

// ...
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'` is not being escaped. Replace it with double quotes `''` so it reads as:

```
SELECT slno FROM `webcrawler`.`web_de`  
where messagedigest='?Ê''?`®o1F±[øT¤?¿!€';
```

EDIT: Too slow! :P

You can also escape it by using `\'` also

Answer (score 0):

the messagedigest value has a quote in it.  If you escape the quote it should work, but...
you might be better off encoding the message digest before trying to write it to the database.

Comment: Could u pl give me some idea as to how can I do encoding of the message digest ?

Comment: @user523956 you could use UUEencode/UUDecode.  There are various implementations out there if you google for them.  There is a sun implementation that used to be part of java, but it isn't part of the official API spec, so it could go away.